# How to make a query of two different fields of a table in a database with PHP, MySQL and AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an autocomplete code, which at the time of typing in the search bar makes a post request to a php file where there is a connection to a database.

What I need to do is that the search engine I have can differentiate between one field of the table in the database of another.

I was using regular expressions to validate, but both fields look alike and there is nothing that can differentiate them

```
========Field1=============Field2=========
|| 8JZu2ls6WVVtiAIb || Ie2XKmIlmqoYr6Bd ||
|| ZKMOM2GttpBlIID6 || 812mHnpZ8hEbbbfe ||
|| E6nfb4BjS357QgO5 || 365dOIlUKEhLBigN ||
|| p1oLLI5JiR7iiMKF || 8uFxy53Hs6rSQC5L ||
==========================================
```

I need the searcher to recognize when to search in one field and when in the other, depending on what is entered in the search bar.

Comment: What do you imagine could be the solution?

Comment: I declare two variables where I assign them a regular expression and then with some conditionals `if` the variables are valid and depending on the value I make a query, but it does not work.